Variant of Quantum Hamming bound for CSS codes
The arguments leading to the Quantum Hamming Bound for non-degenerate $[[n,k,d = 2t+1]]$ codes
$$\sum_{j=0}^t 3^j \binom{n}{j} ≤ 2^{n-k}$$
can be manipulated to find a stronger related bound for non-degenerate CSS codes,
$$\left(\sum_{j=0}^t \binom{n}{j}\right)^2 ≤ 2^{n-k}.$$
Note that this is simply the classical Hamming bound with the left-hand side squared.
Examples:

the quantum Hamming codes $[[2^r-1, 2^r - 2r - 1, 3]]$ fall short of the normal QHB but would saturate this one, as LHS = RHS = $2^{2r}$,
Shor $[[9,1,3]]$ code has a strict inequality $100 < 256$,
Gottesman $[[2^r, 2^r - r - 2, 3]]$ codes violate it but they aren't CSS,
surface codes violate it but they are degenerate. (example disputed in comments)

I think this is pretty straightforward, but I can't seem to find it anywhere to cite it. Does it have a name? Or perhaps it's wrong, can you help me find a counterexample? Or did I just discover something?

Am I missing something, or is the statement that "surface codes violate it but they are degenerate" wrong? It's simply a matter of plugging in $n = (2t+1)^2$ and $k=1$, right?

@Damion It seems you're right, I can't remember after those months why I thought that was the case.

This seems to be similar to what is discussed here, which is the only place I've seen perfect CSS codes defined: The [[15,7,3]] code is "only perfect as a CSS code, i.e., the 2^4 Z stabilizer syndromes are exactly enough to correct the 1 + 15 possible trivial or weight-one X errors,
and similarly for Z errors."

Thank you for the reference. They seem to be using exactly the meaning I have in mind (covering X and Z stabilizer syndromes separately). Please note that it is [[15,7,3]] and $2^4$ not 24, but I can't edit this in the answer (too few characters). Then $(\binom{15}{0} + \binom{15}{1})^2= 2^{15-7} = 256$.
